# How can i retrieve List of YouTube Channels, Order By subscriber count?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

is it possible to get list of channels along with their subscriber count either in ascending or descending order. Does YouTube API provide any specific calls ?

I haven’t found relevant answers to my requirement in Stack Overflow, How do i retrieve YouTube Channels List, Order By subscriber count ? Please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: Documentation mentions how to get subs of specific channel by using channel Id. I didn’t find a way to retrieve list of channel based on subs.

Comment: List of channels by category Id, Region e.t.c. are mentioned in document but list of channels by subscribers count is not mentioned.